# How to query IMAP server for new mails when I have lots of accounts

Tags: imap

Now, I want to write a program(daemon) to query IMAP server for new mails and notify clients when their new mails arrive. And I have thousands of email accounts, so I want to know how to accomplish this efficiently and easily.

From my understanding, I know two possible solutions.

- query email accounts one by one, which is 'poll' style
- use IMAP idle extension and event driven I/O (epoll) [reference](http://www.quora.com/Cue-formerly-Greplin/How-does-Greplin-query-Google-Mail-for-new-mails)

I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of both solutions.

I also want to know is there any library(C, C++, PHP, Python) can help me to do such thing. Or how can I do this by myself.

Or a third solution?

Comment: Of course there are libraries in all languages offering code to work with imap servers. Google for "imap <you language>".

Comment: Python has imaplib, but it doesn't support IDLE.  There's a third-party 'imaplib2' which does.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of IMAP IDLE is reduced overhead and (probably) increased responsiveness.

The advantage of polling is that it's inherently supported by all servers, whereas IDLE isn't supported by all servers.

As for libraries, @Max points out imaplib and imaplib2 in Python. I'm sure the other languages you mention have similar libraries.

As for third option, instead of IMAP libraries, you might look into using [context.io](http://context.io).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a third option if it is *your* imap server. In that case you could bypass the protocol itself and monitor the servers database itself for changes. That sould be much more efficient, since it omits the whole communication layer.