# Android: Querying a mail server

Tags: android, imap

Is there documentation on how to query an IMAP mail server in Android? I'm trying to make an app that simply checks for unread messages.

Comment: Of course there are libraries in all languages offering code to work with imap servers. Google for "imap <you language>". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743165/how-to-query-imap-server-for-new-mails-when-i-have-lots-of-accounts

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use javamail. There is much documentation for javamail, and [here is an android port](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/).